# Can't use inline backgroundImage in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux

Realised the proper way to change styles in React is by keeping them in the store.

I did just that but now React just wont render the proper background, only shows white one.

I configure store this way:

```
const stylesDefaultState = {
    background:{
        beds: './assets/bedsA.jpg'
    }
}
```

I access this via props in the component:

```
    let bedsBackgroundImage = `url(${this.props.styles.background.beds})`

    let bedsStyle = {
        backgroundImage: bedsBackgroundImage
    }


    return(
        <div id='beds'  style={bedsStyle}>
    )
```

And this and any other similiar approach won't work. I check whats going on in the devtools and it looks okay (although its slashed by devtools) but still wont cooperate. Picture:
http://prntscr.com/hdfxgh

I could try different approach, but any other I came up with ends up not being held in store, which means that when I exit this component in the browser (by going to a different page for example) the style gets reset to default, and I need the ability to change it AND save it, that's why I used redux for that.

Edit:
It works when I ling to the image hosted somewhere, but still cant force it to work when specifing a path to the file. If only I got any error, clues on what's wrong, but it looks like it should be working.

Comment: If it works when you use an image hosted elsewhere, it sounds like a problem with your image path. What does your file structure look like?

Comment: Sounds like a Webpack issue with building your images. To get local images to work in my app, I use the `CopyWebpackPlugin` to copy over my `img` directory into the `dist` directory.

Comment: I think my path is correct, I moved my css files to the same directory as JS files and tested the path in css file, it is correct. It looks like this http://prntscr.com/hdhg74
@ChaseDeAnda which is weird, because I dont have this problem when I set background image via CSS

Comment: If you're going to hardcode the path, it needs to be relative to the location of the output file (typically bundle.js) thus Chase's answer regarding using the copy plugin

Comment: Another plugin and even more code for such a simple change I think thats enough for me, I think im gonna either stick to linking to the image hosted elsewhere or just switch classes on click. 1 line in pure JS turning into multifile, multiplugin thing is terryfing